# How to redirect after successfully login to other class in gwt and how to set the session timeout and its response after session timeout in gwt?

Tags: session, gwt, servlets, redirect, authentication

can you please tell me how to redirect to next page after successfully login in GWT?
I have created the service interface and its implementions but dont know how to redirect the page after login authentication. 
Share your views guyz. 
and also tell me how to get sessiontimeout and then redirect automatically to login page in gwt.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window.Location.replace(String newURL)` to switch pages.

As for the session timeout, that depens on what kind of session management you are using.

The easiest would be to include the information "session expired" in every RPC call you make, for example with a custom exception:

Server

```
public String myRpcCall() throws SessionExpiredException {
  if(!SessionManager.isSessionValid()) { // depends on your session management
     throw new SessionExpiredException;
  }
  return some_stuff(); // whatever you want to do
}
```

Client

```
public doCall() {
   AsyncCallback<String> cb = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
         if(caught instanceof SessionExpiredException) {
            // inform the user and redirect to login page
            Window.Location.replace("login.html");
         }
         // handle other errors
      }
      // TODO onSuccess(String)
   };
   service.myRpcCall(cb);  // your rpc call goes here
}
```

Comment: Do i need to create different-different HTML files for login, logout and index page? Right now i have only one html file for my project. here i added the rootpanel of login form class. 

Then i m calling the RPC service over login button and this service is authenticating the username and password.

now where i should write the page redirect code? IN onSuccess method or in my Server side service class.

and can you tell the exact path of page like Window.Location.Replace("com/gwt/model/client/mainIndex"). Is it write?

Comment: You can, but you don't need to. You can also make multiple panels and attach/detach them accordingly. After the RPC call is complete, `onSuccess(...)` of your `AsyncCallback` is called, so you'd want to put your redirect there. The parameter for replace is an URL, so it would be your HTML page you want to redirect to (see redirect to login in answer)

Comment: How can i add the different different classes like login and logout in same html's panel. because we can mention our entrypoint and onModuleLoad in only one class. so whenever this entrypoint class load, that tym whole panels are loaded...

Comment: and how can i add rootpanel in class which does not implement with a entrypoint...??

Comment: `RootPanel.get()` always returns the same panel, even when used from different classes. Honestly tough, I think this has nothing to do with the original question anymore. StackOverflow is for help with specific questions and problems, not giving comprehensive tutorials of a broad topic. Thats what the GWT documentation is for.

Comment: Yeah i know that. but i am really confused about all that. so just asking you. BTW thanx alot for making me clear. 
Thanx again.